# date parsing error in android

Tags: android, parsing, datetime

here is the code

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";
public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";
SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT) ;

    try {
    String dateString = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ReminderDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME));

    Date date =  (Date) datetimeFormat.parse(reminder.getString(dateString);

    mCalendar.setTime(date); 
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        Log.e("edit_activity", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

it is not parsing date as all the values are fetched but date is not parsed so logcat is showing an error.

```
error::06-11 14:08:59.320: E/edit_activity(361): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2012-03-11 13:14:49
```

pleaseee help me out

Comment: what kk means in a date format?

Comment: @mihail: 'k' is hour in day (1-24) as opposed to 'H' (0-23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to give 'T', in DateFormat, instead you can specify SimpleDateFormat as below:

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";

kk = Hours in 1-24 format
hh= hours in 1-12 format
KK= hours in 0-11 format
HH= hours in 0-23 format
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared `DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss"`, however your time is in format `"yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss"` - hence it can't parse it.  Remove `'T'` from your format - and you'll be fine.

I just tested with this code:

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";
public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";

SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT) ;

try {
    String dateString = "2012-03-11 13:14:49";
    Date date =  (Date) datetimeFormat.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date);

} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it worked just fine, printing `Sun Mar 11 13:14:49 GMT 2012`

Comment: Oh, wait... why is it 'kk'?  Shouldn't it be 'hh' instead?

Comment: @AleksG: 'k' is hour in day (1-24) as opposed to 'H' (0-23).

Comment: Ok, see it now.  I updated my answer putting my test code, which worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove the T character from your string, then use

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

are you sure about these kk's?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just miss a ")" in

```
Date date =  (Date) datetimeFormat.parse(reminder.getString(dateString);
```

Can you just print reminder.getString(dateString), does it right?